# antx.tomcat.start does not support the nested "debug" element

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat6

When I start the tomcat in debug mode, it gives me the above error.

```
<macrodef name="tomcat">
    <element name="options" optional="yes" />
    <sequential>
        <delete dir="server/cache" failonerror="no" />
        <delete dir="server/logs" failonerror="no" />
        <delete dir="server/workspace" failonerror="no" />
        <delete dir="server/tomcat/logs" failonerror="no" />
        <antx:tomcat.start>
            <tomcat catalinahome="${catalina.home}" port="${server.port}" />
            <enovia enoviahome="${enovia.server.home}">
                <memory size="medium" />
                <classpath>
                    <pathelement location="${alt.jdk.home}/lib/tools.jar" />
                    <pathelement location="${webapp.home}/WEB-INF/classes" />
                    <pathelement location="${webapp.home}/WEB-INF/lib" />
                    <pathelement location="${catalina.home}/lib/jsp-api.jar" />
                                            <pathelement location="${catalina.home}/lib/servlet-api.jar" />
                </classpath>
                <bootstrap connectstring="${oracle.sid}" driver="${oracle.driver}" password="${schema.password}" user="${schema.user}" />
            </enovia>
            <webapp location="${webapp.home}" />
            <javahome location="${alt.jdk.home}" />
            <options />
        </antx:tomcat.start>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="tomcat-start-debug" description="start tomcat in debug mode">
    <tomcat>
        <options>
            <jrebel location="${jrebel.jar}" />
            <debug transport="dt_socket" address="8998" server="y" suspend="n" />
        </options>
    </tomcat>
</target>
```

I have the same configuration in some other project, and it works. I am trying to get an solution for this. If anyone knows how to fix this, it would be helpful if its shared here.

Thanks,
Sandeep